# How to print last elements of array

Tags: ruby, arrays

how do I print all elements of an array after the second element ex:

```
ARR=["a","b","c","d","f"]
```

I want to print c d f

```
ARR=["cat","dog","horse"]
```

I want to print horse

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just as easy as
`p ARR[2..-1]`
where 2 and -1 are indexes of an elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) with range or [`Array#drop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-drop)

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d","f"]
arr[2..-1]
# => ["c", "d", "f"]
arr.drop(2)
# => ["c", "d", "f"]

arr = ["cat","dog","horse"]
arr[2..-1]
# => ["horse"]
arr.drop(2)
# => ["horse"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#last`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-last) method

```
arr.last(arr.size - 2)
```